# Getting Lists from csv file

Tags: java

I am trying to get a list of data with the same way of trade from this csv file:

```
TRD1,0,Kobe,Jordan,Offline,
TRD2,3,jayson,Mitchell,Online,
TRD3,6,Paul,Garnett,Offline,
TRD4,456,Doncic,Ben,Online,
TRD5,555,James,Sebastian,Online,
TRD6,3271,james,harden,online,
TRD8,3271,Hobe,Bry,offline,
```

Code:

```
public List<TradeRecord> getWayOfTrade(String wayOfTrade) {

    List<TradeRecord> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TradeRecord tr: tradeList) {
        if (tr.getWayOfTrade().equals(wayOfTrade)) {
            list.add(tr);
        }
    }
    return list; 
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(tMgr.getWayOfTrade("offline"));
```

The code seems to only output the first **offline** trade it finds, what needs to be changed so it can output **all** the offline trades instead?

Comment: The code you have given makes no sense as they don't correlate with the question you are asking. However, it may seem its because the one entry in the csv has 'Offline' with a lowercase 'o'?

Comment: I think you code is no problem,but realization does not match expectations.

Answer (score 2):

`String.equals()` is case sensitive and it appears that there's only one record with the value 'offline'. The other potential matches are spelt 'Offline'.

You could try:

```
if (tr.getWayOfTrade().equalsIgnoreCase(wayOfTrade)) {
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @rwd If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.